# Cookie Redirect Script

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am quite a noob concerning programming but learning. I have 3 pages, index.htm, ef.htm & dh.htm. On e.g. linkedin I have a link to ef.htm and want, that if you have been to ef.htm, you will always be redirected to ef.htm, when entering index.htm or dh.htm. The same vice versa.
I created/found following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
var COOKIE_NAME = 'testcookie';
$go = $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME);
if ($go == null) {
    $.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, 'test', { path: '/', expires: 10 });
    window.location = "/dh.php"
}
else {
}
});
</script>
```

The .js are added to my directory.
How can I make that script work like I want to?
I tried 500 different things, but no success. Is there even a more elegant method? ALl things I found on stackoverflow, where not exactly what I wanted or dont work.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is the current outcome? Do you get an error message or does it fail silently? If the latter is true, what's in the `else` part of your `if`/`then` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will do what you want.

There are three files: index.html, ef.html, and dh.html.  Just copy/paste the code into those three files and it should do what you want.

Note that most of the javascript/jQuery on the page is just to make the example work. The only jQuery you really need to make your page redirect work is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            fav_site = $.cookie('fav_website');

            if (fav_site == 'ef') {
                window.location.href ='ef.html';
            }else if (fav_site == 'dh') {
                window.location.href = 'dh.html';
            }
    }); //END $(document).ready()

</script>
```

---

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                fav_site = $.cookie('fav_website');
                alert('Cookie Value is now: [' +fav_site+ ']');

                if (fav_site == 'ef') {
                    window.location.href ='ef.html';
                }else if (fav_site == 'dh') {
                    window.location.href = 'dh.html';
                }

                $('#mybutta').click(function() {
                    $.cookie('fav_website', 'ef', { path: '/', expires: 10 });
                    window.location.href = 'ef.html';
                });
                $('#mybuttb').click(function() {
                    $.cookie('fav_website', 'dh', { path: '/', expires: 10 });
                    window.location.href = 'dh.html';
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>MAIN PAGE (Index.html)</h1>
    <input id="mybutta" type="button" value="GoTo Site EF">
    <input id="mybuttb" type="button" value="Visit Site DH">

</body>
</html>
```

---

**DH.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $.cookie('fav_website', '', { path: '/', expires: 10 });
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                });
                $('#mybuttox').click(function() {
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>Page DH DH DH DH DH DH DH DH DH DH</h1>
    <input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Reset Cookies (Erase All)">
    <input id="mybuttox" type="button" value="Return to Main Page">

</body>
</html>
```

---

**EF.HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
        <style>
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $.cookie('fav_website', '', { path: '/', expires: 10 });
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                });
                $('#mybuttox').click(function() {
                    window.location.href = 'index.html';
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <h1>Page EF</h1>
    <input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Reset Cookies (Erase All)">
    <input id="mybuttox" type="button" value="Return to Main Page">

</body>
</html>
```